# bash curl | grep a specific website content

Tags: html, web, curl, web-scraping, grep

I'm trying to extract a specific piece of information from a website, but the content seems to be included in the class definition:

```
<div class= "some_div_class">
  <strong content="999" itemprop="price" class="strong_class">
      999
  </strong>
</div>
```

I'm targeting the "999", which I can if I do:

```
curl -s url |grep -zPo '<strong content="999" itemprop="price" class="strong_class">\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</strong>)'
```

If the "999" is in the content though, and it changes, grep would become invalid. Wildcards wouldn't return anything

Comment: Could you use a command line parser like xmllint? http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please(!) have a look at the following urls before you attempt to parse a website with RegEx:

- [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)
- [How do I extract data from an HTML or XML file?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/113)

With an HTML/XML parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) it's as simple as:

```
xidel -s "<url or file>" -e '//div[@class="some_div_class"]/strong/@content'
```

or

```
xidel -s "<url or file>" -e '//div[@class="some_div_class"]/normalize-space(strong)'
```